# how to get `props.location.state` after first render of the linked component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two components `products` and `partners`, there is link in `products` that looks like this:

```
<Link to={{
            pathname:"/partners",
            state: { from: props.location.pathname },
        }}>
    To Partners
</Link>
```

now in the `partners` if I do:

```
const location = useLocation();
const from = location?.state?.from;
console.log(from)
```

on initial render I get the correct output `/products`, but the problem is that `partners` component rerenders multiple time not just once so I get `undefined` after the initial render, so my question is how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you share the whole component, and the different routes

Comment: You could save the route state locally if you need to hold on to it after the initial render. I *think* the route state should persist if I'm not mistaken, but depending on the type of router and anything else going on it may be clearing it unexpectedly. Can you share a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are working with though.